# Qualcomm Atheros AR8132 link speed pronlem

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, atheros

I am a newbie to Linux. I want to use an old computer to a backups backup. That computer has a Msi ms-7592 ver 5.2 g41m-p28 motherboard and a Qualcomm Atheros AR8132 Fast Ethernet onboard network interface.  (rev c0).
I set everythig up, my problem is the network link speed. I only get 100 mbit/S connection. I have gigabit internet connection, my router ican handle gigabit speed. The ethernet cable is working fine, i tested on a windows laptop. I have another computer with the same spec, it has the same problem.  Ubuntu version : 20.04.5 LTS
What can i do?

Comment: You do realize "***Fast ethernet***" was a standard capable of carrying "*traffic at the nominal rate of 100 Mbit/s*" and not the later "***Gigabit ethernet***" that was capable of 1000 Mbit/s.    Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet etc.  Software cannot make hardware do something it's not capable of.

Comment: Based on the spec sheet, that is on msi website the network card can handle the gigabit ethernet conection. "Supports PCI Express LAN 10/100/1000 Fast Ethernet by Atheros AR8131M"

Comment: Your question specifies AR8132 (Fast Ethernet) and not AR8132M (Gigabit ethernet).  The M is a later chipset than what your question mentions.  Which chipset exists on your actual motherboard as your question differs significantly to your last comment.